# Laravel lighthouse graphql directory structure with a nuxtjs front-end

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

having some issues getting lighthouse and nuxtjs to work together properly.

lighthouse requires a `schema.graphql` file inside the graphql directory, inside of this `schema.graphql` file you have the option to either place all of your code inside of this file, or split your code into specific graphql files (this is what I did) e.g.

```
#import routes/*.graphql
#import posts/*.graphql
#import index/*.graphql

type Query


type Mutation
```

my other graphql files contain some file specific code, e.g. `post.graphql` contains this

```
extend type Query {
    posts: [Post!]! @all
}


type Post {
    id:ID!,
    title:String!,
    content: String!
}
```

Now for simple queries this works fine, but when I started adding mutations things got a bit confusing.

So, I added a new file called `post-mutations.graphql` inside of the graphql directory in my laravel back-end, inside of this file I extend the mutation type

```
extend type Mutation {
    createPost(input: createIndexInput! @spread): Post @create
}


input createPostInput{
    title: String!,
    slug: String!
}
```

this works completly fine, if I go to graphql-playground and call the mutation this works.

Now when I try calling the mutation on my front end (nuxt) is where it starts to break apart, so on my front-end I have a directory called apollo, inside of this directoy is where my graphql lives. I also have a file called `post-mutations.graphql` inside of this file is where I call the mutation that I created on the laravel back-end side

```
mutation createPost($index: createPostInput!) {
  createPost(input: $index) {
    title,
    slug
  }
}
```

Now the problem here is that my front-end does not have access to the `createPostInput` type that I declared in my laravel app, so graphql throws an error about now knowing `createPostInput`, I thought about adding the input type in my front-end but if I have to do this for every type this just seems like I'm needlessly repeating myself?

also just a sidenote, I use the `graphql` extension inside of phpStorm, when I start phpStorm it asks me if I want to introspect my schema, if I do this it creates a new `schema.grapgql` file at the root of my directory, inside of this file are various declarations that seem to improve IDE type completion, maybe this is something worth looking into?